# Qual a diferença entre uma Entidade e um Modelo (do MVC e afins)?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, mvc, model, entidade

Na orientação a objetos ambos são classes geralmente usadas para representar algo que será persistido (não que seja obrigatório persisti-los), mas qual a diferença entre ambos? Ou são nomes diferentes para a mesma coisa?

Comment: Creio que entidade é a nomenclatura que é utilizada pelo ORM. hibernate por exemplo. No meu caso... Eu agora só utilizo o modelo....

Comment: @DNick essa sua resposta parece ser só sobre _controllers_, não tem nenhuma relação direta com essa pergunta. Além disso, essa é uma pergunta que não é aplicada a uma linguagem específica

Comment: @Costamilam, concordo. Comentário removido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estou imaginando que no contexto que está usando é a mesma coisa com nomes diferentes, e depende um pouco da disciplina que está adotando.

Em MVC mesmo o termo é *model*. Não vejo as pessoas que entendem de MVC usando outro termo para isso. E na verdade a palavra pode ser usada em dois contextos no MVC, você pode falar que é uma classe é um dos modelos a ser usado no modelo como um todo, eu estou considerando que está falando do tipo de objeto individual e não no modelo como um todo. O modelo também pode ser uma estrutura, o desenho inteiro com todos os modelos individuais, ou seja *model* pode ser o termo usado para designar algo que vai além da entidade simples.

Entidade é um termo usado em outros contextos para a mesma coisa. É usado em diagramas DER, ou em ORMs ou principalmente em DDD. Mas é a classe do objeto que você quer declarar para montar o modelo geral.

Como as pessoas aprendem tudo mais ou menos começam misturar os termos e contextos, aí vira bagunça e "ninguém" mais entende o que quer dizer cada coisa, e a maioria não se preocupa que está confuso. Chega um ponto que todo mundo está ensinando errado. Um caso que eu sempre falo é sobre [campo e atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101), quase todo mundo usa errado até porque tem muitos livros ensinando errado.

Eu dei uma pesquisada o que o pessoal tem escrito por aí e há muita confusão, muita bobagem sobre os termos por não conseguirem definir com clareza o limite dele. Por isso não garanto que minha resposta é uma verdade absoluta, pode ser contestada, mas ela foi pensada e tem critérios.

Por exemplo eu não cai na besteira de falar que um *model* envolve persistência (digo isso porque vi muita gente falando assim nas pesquisas e garanto que isto está errado, por essa razão pode ter aprendido errado). É comum envolver, mas não precisa. O modelo nunca definiu de onde vem ou para onde vai o dado daquele objeto, poderia ser um *stream*, poderia ser efêmero.

Entidade envolve persistência? Não sei, neste caso eu não vou garantir. O fato é que nunca vi algum lugar que ele seja um termo nativo do MVC, então se ele é usado em outro contexto, ainda que junto do MVC ou até sobrepondo no mesmo mecanismo (a classe do objeto definido), vai depender desse contexto. Se a entidade está sendo usada no contexto de um ORM aí acho que a persistência faz sentido.

Então a mesma classe está sendo usada para duas implementações diferentes (MVC e ORM) e por isso ela recebe nome diferente em cada caso, mesmo sendo uma coisa só.

E entendo que não precisa ter uma relação de um para um entre o modelo e entidade, ainda que seja o mais comum.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quem deu o negativo poderia me dizer o que tem de errado para eu corrigir, assim todos se beneficiam e aprendem. Já que a pessoa sabe que tem algo errado não é justo com a comunidade guardar só para si.